# better way to edit base function arguments already used by other developers

Tags: project

For example, if there is a network function(simplify #A) performing a basic socket request and receive behavior. Everyone in the project has already widely used #A in different sections of the project. But one day, #A's arguments needs to be updated due to insufficient information.

I can imagine someone just edit #A directly but remain other functions which already used #A to revise by the owners themselves. But is there any better way, from the beginning, to improve this kind of dirty work during corporation?

Comment: What programming language? Do you thaught about polymorphism and method overloading?

Comment: not specify any programming language here. I think you've already said the keyword, Polymorphism and method overloading for both object-oriented language and not object-oriented ones. With the answer from @Andersen, I can come up with solutions to solve my problem.
Thank you both!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are we talking life running code here?

Keeping everyone at the table or in the loop of changes would be preferable, I think.

Enforcing changes that break code if left unattended is always bad. Adding Optional parameters with base values are pretty nice, especially when their base values improve without breaking anything. Other than that, duplicates or extended classes with increasing functionality would be nice too so you can upgrade at your own pace.

Comment: With the comment from @kedenk and answer from you. I consider Polymorphism and method overloading are the answer I was asking. Thank you both.